# How can we include standard tabs like chatter, knowledge in lightning component for lightning app in browser?

Tags: chatter, lightning-aura-components, knowledge

I want to inlcude chatter and knowledge standard functionality in a lightning component. Is this possible?
Currently there is a new tag in lightning for including chatter

```
<forceChatter:feed type="News" />
```

But this solution is not working for browser lightning application.
If there is any way to include the standard tabs that will also do.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a wrong type "News" It is necessary to provide correct feed type.

Try with following feed type. It will show feeds from all chatter groups.

```
<aura:component >
    <forceChatter:feed type="groups"/>
</aura:component>
```

[image]

Comment: Ya, I did make a mistake in the type attribute. But now that I corrected the code, its still not displaying the feeds. The screenshot u have put here - is this component included in a standalone app or Salesforce1? Coz I am getting the following error in console when I tried the type="groups" :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined

Comment: @VedaP it is a lightning component.

Comment: And have you included this in a lightning application or exposed this as a lightning component tab in Salesforce1? Thanks

Comment: @VedaP It is exposed as lightning page tab and component is included in that lightning page.

Comment: Ohh thanks. Yes lightning page is working, But my requirement is that it should be included in the lightning application which we create from developer console. In short a browser app. Can you help me in this approach?